# Textbook MergeSort Implementation in SQL (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to implement a textbook version of Mergesort in SQL and try not to use plpgsql. I just want to use SQL. I use Postgres as my database system. I've tried everything, but unfortunately I can't get any further.

My Mergesort function looks like this so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mergesort(A double precision[], p integer, r integer)
RETURNS double precision[] AS $$
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN p < r THEN mergesort(A,p,floor((p+r)/2)::integer) 
             WHEN p < r THEN mergesort(A,floor((p+r)/2)::integer+1,r)
             WHEN p < r THEN merge(A,p,floor((p+r)/2)::integer,r)
             ELSE A
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I'm trying to get something like this executable and working (I'm aware that in my code example CASE doesn't execute all three calls that are necessary, I haven't found a solution yet and unfortunately I don't know how to assign the result of Mergesort in the recursive call back to variable A).

Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this problem?

Only for Information:
The merge function is already implemented and executable in plpgsql. (Perhaps I try to rewrite it in SQL in a next step).

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge(A double precision[], p integer, q integer, r integer) 
RETURNS double precision[] AS $$
DECLARE
 n1 integer := q-p+1;
 n2 integer := r-q;
 L double precision[]; 
 Ri double precision[];
 g integer;
 h integer; 
BEGIN
 L = ARRAY[n1+1]; 
 Ri = ARRAY[n2+1];
 FOR i in 1..(n1+1) LOOP
    L[i] = A[p+i-1];
 END LOOP;
 FOR j in 1..n2+1 LOOP
    Ri[j] = A[q+j];
 END LOOP;
 L[n1+1] = 'Infinity';
 Ri[n2+1] = 'Infinity';
 g = 1;
 h = 1;
 FOR k in p..r LOOP
    IF L[g] <= Ri[h] THEN
        A[k] = L[g];
        g = g + 1;
    ELSE
        A[k] = Ri[h];
        h = h + 1; 
    END IF;
 END LOOP;
 RETURN A;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out by now and wanted to share the solution with you. 
I have now chosen a functional algorithm, which is easier to implement in SQL than the imperative one.

Mergesort:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mergesort(A double precision[]) 
RETURNS double precision[] AS $$
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN 1 < array_length(A,1) 
              THEN merge(mergesort(A[1:floor((1+array_length(A,1))/2)::integer]),
                         mergesort(A[floor((1+array_length(A,1))/2)::integer+1:array_length(A,1)]),
                         1,
                         1,
                         ARRAY[]::double precision[])
             ELSE A
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Merge:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge(A1 double precision[],A2 double precision[], i integer, j integer,acc double precision[]) 
RETURNS double precision[] AS $$
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN (i > array_length(A1,1) and j > array_length(A2,1)) THEN acc
             WHEN i > array_length(A1,1) THEN merge(A1,A2,i,j+1,array_append(acc,A2[j]))
             WHEN j > array_length(A2,1) THEN merge(A1,A2,i+1,j,array_append(acc,A1[i]))
             WHEN A1[i] <  A2[j] THEN merge(A1,A2,i+1,j,array_append(acc, A1[i]))
             WHEN A1[i] >= A2[j] THEN merge(A1,A2,i,j+1,array_append(acc, A2[j]))                
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```